# Presentation software for ipad which works also on windows 7 laptop for remote control

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation, ms-office

Very soon I have a presentation at school. and would like a suggestion regarding the application for iOS which can I use for the Powerpoint presentation. I would like an app that allows me to change a slide a page on my iPad, and have that reflect automatically also on my laptop (has Windows 7).

What software I need for tablet and laptop, and what steps do I follow to do remote presentation?

Answer (score 1):

There are several apps that will allow you to remotely view your laptop's Powerpoint, as well as remotely control it. Here is one such application:

[i-Clickr PowerPoint Remote](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/i-clickr-powerpoint-remote/id366755661?mt=8)

Comment: This 8€ application has no ratings ? how ?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a remote desktop client such as [Splashtop](http://www.splashtop.com/home)